# How do I specify different layouts for portrait and landscape orientations?

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, portrait

I've seen references to being able to specify two separate layout xml files for an activity, one for Portrait and one for Landscape.  I've not been to find any information on how to do that though.  How do I specify for each activity which xml file is it's portrait layout and which is the Landscape layout?

Is it also possible to specify different layouts for different screen sizes?  If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Create a **`layout-land`** directory and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

Comment: Does that mean all activities need to define both a landscape and a portrait view if I do this?

Comment: No, if no layout-land definition exists it just uses the XML layout in the standard layout directory.

Comment: in my case , layout-land is not working when i am using , android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: Remove orientation from android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: When I change the orientation the activity does not switch the layout, staying with the layout when the activity is created. If I remove orientation from `android:configChanges`, the activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 64):

You just have to put it under separate folders with different names depending on orientation and resolution, the device will automatically select the right one for its screen settings

More info here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

under "Resource directory qualifiers for screen size and density"

Comment: Only works for OS versions 1.6 or higher.  If you want to support 1.5, you need this link:  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-support-1.5.html

Comment: @Silvio Donnini  - links no longer have the required information.

Comment: @itsaboutcode Yes it does:  Go down to "Using configuration qualifiers"

Answer (score 30):

**For Mouse lovers!** I say right click on resources folder and `Add new resource file`, and from Available qualifiers select the `orientation` :

[image]

---

But still you can do it manually by say, adding the sub-folder "layout-land" to

"Your-Project-Directory\app\src\main\res"

since then any layout.xml file under this sub-folder will only work for landscape mode **automatically**.

Use "layout-port" for portrait mode.

Comment: This worked for me. I added a new layout file as instructed with the same name as the portrait version. Android Studio automatically created a folder for that layout. One layout for portrait and another for landscape.  The new layout automatically gets displayed when rotating screen.

Answer (score 25):

Fastest way for Android Studio 3.x.x and Android Studio 4.x.x

1.Go to the design tab of the activity layout

2.At the top you should press on the orientation for preview button, there is a option to create a landscape layout (check image), a new folder will be created as your xml layout file for that particular orientation

[image]

**Update:** On newer versions the options have been moved to the context menu of the .xml filename button. (Big thanks to Oliver Hoffmann for pointing that out).

[image]

Comment: One of the easiest and Shortest way to deal with landscape layout

Comment: This answer should be chosen

Comment: On newer AndroidStudio versions this option moved a bit to the context menu of the .xml filename button

Answer (score 22):

Just a reminder:

Remove `orientation` from `android:configChanges` attribute for the activity in your manifest `xml` file if you defined it:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

Comment: what if I need to have android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" in my manifest, as some of my fragments can be in both orientation and some don't, but still need separate layouts for landscape and portrait for those fragments that can change orientation dynamically?

Comment: If I remove the orientation from android:configChanges the activity is destroyed when the orientation changes.

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest way in the latest Android versions is by going to Design mode of an XML (not Text).

Then from the menu, select option - Create Landscape Variation.
This will create a landscape xml without any hassle in a few seconds. The latest Android Studio version allows you to create a landscape view right away.

[image]

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new directory `layout-land`, then create `xml` file with same name in  `layout-land` as it was `layout` directory and align there your content for Landscape mode.

Note that id of content in both `xml` is same.

Answer (score 4):

The last line below is an example for applying two quantifiers: **landscape and smallest width**(600dp) screen. Update 600dp with the ones you need.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml                # For handsets
res/layout-land/main_activity.xml           # For handsets in landscape
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml        # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw600dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets in landscape
```

The above applies to dimens as well

```
res/values/dimens.xml                # For handsets
res/values-land/dimens.xml           # For handsets in landscape
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml        # For 7” tablets
res/values-sw600dp-land/dimens.xml   # For 7” tablets in landscape
```

A useful device metrics: https://material.io/tools/devices/

Answer (score 2):

Or use this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <!-- Add your UI elements inside the inner most linear layout -->

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click res folder,
2. New -> Android Resource File
3. in Available qualifiers, select Orientation,
4. add to Chosen qualifier
5. in Screen orientation, select Landscape
6. Press OK

<s>Using Android Studio 3.4.1, **it no longer creates `layout-land` folder**. It will create a folder and put two layout files together.</s>

[image]

Comment: Incorrect. You are not using the folder view mode (like "Project"). You are probably using "Android" view mode, which groups files together like in your screenshot in virtual folders, but the actual folder structure is still how every other post here describes.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio Chipmunk, the options you are looking for are here.

For landscape, the option is "Create Landscape Qualifier" in the XML name drop-down. 
For different screen sizes, the option is "Create Tablet Qualifier"

these have been moved from previous Android Studio versions.

[image]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74047314/3718756