# Android Home Screen Widget (icon, label - style)

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to create an icon/widget (1 cell x 1 cell) that can be placed on the home screen of android. The widget will look and act exactly like the other standard shortcuts in android. It will have an icon and under that a label, it will be selectable with the trackball (highlight able) it will be highlighted when it is selected/clicked.

How do I go about creating this home screen widget?

Do I have to create the widget myself using code/xml or is there some standard xml, style, theme, code that I can use to ensure that the widget will have the same style/theme as the other home screen widgets?

I currently have the following

res/drawable/corners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Corners">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#CC222222"  />
    <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

res/layout/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Widget"
    android:layout_width="72dip"
    android:layout_height="72dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    style="@android:style/Widget"   
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/WidgetIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WidgetLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/corners"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The resulting widget looks some what close, but its not selectable, it doesn't get highlighted when clicked and the label isn't exactly in the correct location or the correct style.

Any ideas, if there is a correct way to do this, or should I just keep working away on the above until I am closer?

Comment: Did you find a solution how it will look exactly like standard label?

Comment: The below answer is correct, you are not suppose to make widgets look like shortcuts as different OSs may display their shortcuts differently! So if you make one for a HTC phone, it may not match the way shortcuts are displayed on a MOTOBLUR phone. Saying that, I did it anyway and made my one look like HTC :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "correct way to do this" is to make a shortcut, and not try to mimic it with an app widget. This has been pointed out repeatedly by the core Android team (notably Romain Guy) on the [android-developers] discussion list, [such as](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/37764678a00adddd/c8f9a7a822023698):

> Widgets should look like widgets, not
>   like shortcuts. The main reason is
>   that there is absolutely NO guarantee
>   about what a shortcut will look like.
>   Other devices (especially ones with
>   custom system UIs like MOTOBLUR or HTC
>   Sense) might have a different look and
>   feel. Or in the next update of Android
>   we might change the way shortcuts are
>   presented.

Comment: looks like creation of the 1x1 widget is the only way to create application icon with 'counter badge'. Is there any way to apply device-specific theme to my layout?

Comment: @Kevin: By my definition of "declaratively", neither an app widget nor a shortcut can be declared declaratively.

Comment: How do you get the name of the widget to show up below the widget on the home screen like it does for apps?

Comment: @toobsco42: Um, put a `TextView` in your app widget's layout, presumably.

Comment: @CommonsWare but how could you get the same text styling with drop shadow to match the other app icon labels?

Comment: @toobsco42: You can't. After all, it is the home screen that is the one that determines what apps look like on the home screen. There are hundreds of home screen implementations pre-installed on the ~1.5 billion Android devices, and there are hundreds more in the Play Store and elsewhere. You can be running on any of them, and they are all welcome to do whatever they want.

Comment: So I guess the general rule of thumb is you shouldn't add a label under a widget

Answer (score 1):

To make your item consistent with the system look and feel is not hard by referencing the system attribute `android:attr/selectableItemBackground`. For example, if you want to make an ImageView in your widget look "selectable" with proper highlighting etc: just do

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    ...
    />
```

There are a lot in `android_sdk_path/platforms/android-x`. Happy digging!

EDIT: I found out later that this simple attribute does not live in SDK < v11. So the best way I know now is to download the appwidget template pack and use it.