# Title of Android AppWidget below widget-icon

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on a small application which should be represented by an AppWidget. 
The AppWidget should look like many other widgets on my HTC Desire. Most of them consist of an icon and a title below the icon. The title always looks identical, it is white text on a black rounded banner. I have not found a way to get this layout without painting all by myself. What do I have to do, to get the app title shown below the AppWidget?

Thank in advance,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 2):

Per a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651631/android-home-screen-widget-icon-label-style/2652961#2652961) this is actually discouraged by the Android UI guidelines: An App shortcut has such text below it, and it may change in future Android releases or in custom skins such as HTC Sense or MOTOblur. A widget should be a wholly contained graphical element without a text label below it. You need to find a way to make graphics / text in your widget which are self identifying to the user.