# Android adding caption to widget

Tags: android, android-widget

i want to add a caption which looks like the default text below an app icon to the widget of my app. Is there any common way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon"
/>
```

Something like this should work. Using the drawableTop/Left/Right attributes will allow you to place an image above the label. A full list of attributes can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Another thing you could try is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_shape"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_above="@id/text"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nice, works fine. But is there any way to get the same background for the text? (grey, rounded corners)

Comment: I can't test it right now, but you could probably use a shape drawable with rounded corners, and do `android:background="@drawable/background"`. I'm not sure whether that would cover only the text, or also the image drawable above as well, though.

Comment: I've added a new suggestion. Again, I can't test right now unfortunately. :( I'm not sure I have the right wording for scaleType (might be fit_center?)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with this answer.
You should not try to do this.

It has been discussed here :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651631/android-home-screen-widget-icon-label-style/2652961#2652961](http://Stackoverflow)