# How do I give a Android App Widget a Label/Name

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I just finished my first app, it works fine and I've made it a homescreen widget. But it doesn't have the name under it. The tutorial I am following says nothing about it, shouldn't this just be the name of the app and be pulled in automatically?

Comment: @AnthonyChatellier Your link doen't open.

Comment: Thanks @Anshuman. This question has been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651631/android-home-screen-widget-icon-label-style/2652961#2652961

Answer (score 61):

You can set the name of your app widget to be displayed in the widget picker by adding `android:label="the name of my appwidget"` to the receiver that handles appwidget related intents in `AndroidManifest.xml`. It is documented in a somewhat obscure place: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#label

Example of use in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.MyWidgetProvider" android:label="My App Widget">
   ...
</receiver>
```

Note: this property was deprecated in API 21, but still works as of API 29.

Comment: Example: `<receiver android:name="WidgetProviderClass" android:label="@string/widgetname" ...>`

Comment: This doesn't add text under the widget on the home screen on Lollipop.

Comment: I don't have a solution for this. I ended up putting text into my app widget. Check out my widget here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.etiennelawlor.eggday

Comment: Nice! Note that the correct ref page is for <receiver>, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element. This field is not deprecated but it is supplanted in API 31 by android:description on the <appwidget-provider>.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the AndroidManifest.xml.  [App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) might be of some help.