# Add widget name to the home screen along with widget

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, appwidgetprovider

I have created a widget for an application. And widget is displaying along with the name under widget tab. When I drag the widget onto the home screen, the name below the widget is missing.

I have already set the label property for the `<receiver></receiver>`.

Is there anything else I need to do or any other configuration to change?

Regards.

Comment: Can you explain better what is the problem?

Comment: @StefanoMunarini Which part you didn't understand? When I put the widget on home screen, I don't get any name\label under it. Receiver tag is just for widget selection screen I think.

Answer (score 2):

> You can set the name of your app widget to be displayed in the widget
>   picker by adding android:label="the name of my appwidget" to the
>   receiver that handles appwidget related intents in
>   AndroidManifest.xml. It is documented in a somewhat obscure place:
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#label

[How do I give a Android App Widget a Label/Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536691/how-do-i-give-a-android-app-widget-a-label-name)

Comment: Or try this either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651631/android-home-screen-widget-icon-label-style/2652961#2652961

Comment: No this does not solve my problem. As I mentioned I could see the name in the widget picket but when I put my 1x1 widget on the home screen I don't see any name under it. For example: Put a Direct Dial widget and associate it with a contact. You will see name of that contact under direct dial widget but in my case I don't see any name\label under 1x1 widget.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334555/is-it-possible-to-get-the-shortcut-layout-of-launcher-and-use-it-in-our-own-widg/25439010#25439010

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say that, it is not possible, because widgets name will be shown in only widgets menu not on home screen in many launchers, But you can use **Shortcuts**.

Shortcuts show the name with icon, they are simple, all data (icon, label, intent) is static, determined at creation time. They can't be updated dynamically, or resized, or scroll. But they match the launcher styling (and can be placed inside folders or the dock) and use less resources than `AppWidgets`.

As @kevin TeslaColl suggested, you should use [Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334555/is-it-possible-to-get-the-shortcut-layout-of-launcher-and-use-it-in-our-own-widg/25439010#25439010)

Comment: Got it, I accepted the answer and given bounty points as well. Can I also provide custom layout to the shortcut just like in case of 1x1 or any size widget?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a label to appear bellow the widget when its placed on the home screen, just place a TextView on your widget xml layout with the label you want