# How to add a label to the widget screen icon?

Tags: android, widget, label

I created a widget but it is in the screen without any label under...
How to add it?

Answer (score 0):

It has been discussed here :

[Android Home Screen Widget (icon, label - style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651631/android-home-screen-widget-icon-label-style/2652961#2652961)