# Widget 1x1 - original Android style of label

Tags: android, android-widget

Does anyone know the exact style of the Icon and Label on the Homescreen?
I want to create a widget with 1x1 with a counter badge.
So i need the exact style of the label with the background color.

I've found this question, but this style is not exactly like the Android standard.
[Android Home Screen Widget (icon, label - style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651631/android-home-screen-widget-icon-label-style)

Comment: What do you mean by exact style? What is it you're looking for? Are you looking for a set of attributes? if so, what attributes? I don't understand what it is you mean when you say "exact style", please elaborate?

Comment: I mean the attributes background color, imageview, text size and color. The layout xml.
So it should look like the original label of Android under the app icon.

For example see this entry from the above link:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Corners">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#CC222222"  />
    <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>

This look similar but not exact like the standard Android label.