# Dynamic car home icon

Tags: android, api

Is there a way of creating a Car Home shortcut that acts like a app widget where I can send dynamic updates like an app widget?

For example, a car home shortcut that displays the current speed.

Comment: What I am talking about is the shortcut in the  Car Home application, not the shortcut to the Car Home application itself.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to dynamically update the shortcut icon for an app.

You'd have to make a custom widget that looks like an app icon. This would be very difficult, as there are many different Android launchers out there (e.g. HTC Sense, Samsung TouchWiz).

See [Android Home Screen Widget (icon, label - style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651631/android-home-screen-widget-icon-label-style) for more about this process.

Comment: What I am talking about is the shortcut in the  Car Home application, not the shortcut to the Car Home application itself.