# Android Widget in App styling

Tags: android, widget

I'm creating a 1x1 Widget for jumping into special parts of my app depending on the configuration.

Everything works fine except the visualisation of the Widget. The widget should look the same as an app on the Homescreen (with an icon and the label below the image). This should work on different android versions with different stylings. Is there a default style to get this working?

Can anyone help?

Comment: The style is different in every launcher, so I don't think there is a way to make sure it's the same in every launcher.

Comment: is there no possibility? how does for example evernote handles this? Or is there another possibility to create bookmarks that point into an app?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651631/android-home-screen-widget-icon-label-style

Comment: thanks a lot that's exactly what I need. I was doing it wrong with a Widget.