# Two different Layouts(for vertical and horizontal)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view

how can i integrate 2 different layouts for my app.

One for a vertical view and one for a horizontal view?

exp.: vertical - Linear Layout
      horizontal - Table Row

greetings and thx in advance!!!

Comment: you mean to say landscape and portrait.?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations

Comment: can u make your question more clear ..?

Comment: yeah two different layouts for landscape and portrait! how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an orientation listener if you want to do it programmatically:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html

Between 0 and 45 degrees, portrait, 45 and 90 landscape, using setContentView().

Or

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources for the xml (and probably right) way to do it.

Best regards.

Comment: The second option would be better than the first.