# How create I dynamic buttons like my design in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, dynamic

I can create dynamic buttons  similar first picture now .I used Tablerow by create buttons similar  first picture . I get  database value  then I set button's  text values . So  Button's text values is dynamic. Because button's text values is same time long, same time short so Button's width is dynamic. Because of this, I can not use Gridview.

Finally I want  to create dynamic buttons  similar  second picture design. How can I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: check this link it will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can define a layout for different screen orientations, like

```
MyProject/
res/
    layout/
        activity.xml
    layout-land/
        activity.xml
```

And the system will take care of displaying the correct view based on the screen orientation