# Android studio switching layouts when device rotates

Tags: android, layout

I am making my 1st ever android app using android studio,

Everything works correctly except switching between portrait and landscape layouts.

What code do i need to insert and, where to get my app to see the layouts I have made.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Are the layouts named the same and is one of them in a directory called `layout-land`? See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations

Comment: I have the layouts in this folder but still nothing

Comment: Ensure that your activity's declaration in AndroidManifest.xml doesn't force portrait mode. i.e set `android:screenOrientation="user"`

Comment: Thanks, I think it may also be a screen resolution problem ,or layout problem, the back ground rotates but the buttons I have on the background cram up to the top of the screen and don't all appear.

Comment: It was as you said , an error with the folders containing the layouts

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new folder called `layout-land` and place it in there.

Ex:
Your layout's current location is `layout/my_layout.xml`, you would place the corresponding landscape layout in `layout-land/my_layout.xml`

Check: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html under "Using configuration qualifiers"

Similar Question:
[How do I specify different layouts for portrait and landscape orientations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations)