# Android highlight component on rotate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a layout in portrait mode with a textview and some buttons that customize the font style of the textview. I would like that by changing the layout orientation to landscape mode, the textview would fill the entire screen.

I definitely do not know how to do it. Alternating two activities? Rotate activity by code and hiding other components (buttons)? What would be the best way?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an xml file in `setContentView`, then just make another xml file with the same name and put it in `res/layout-land` and it will automatically switch.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) for more, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations) question.