# Admob banner partially covers fullscreen video when landscape orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

how to define a vertical linearlayout in my kotlin code so that the views don't overlap between the banner and other content?

The problem is that admob ads cover the video player content when in landscape orientation

and this in myprogrammatcally

```
    override fun onShowCustomView(view: View, callback: CustomViewCallback, requestedOrientation: Int) {
        val currentTab = tabsManager.currentTab
        if (customView != null) {
            try {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                logger.log(TAG, "Error hiding custom view", e)
            }

            return
        }

        try {
            view.keepScreenOn = true
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            logger.log(TAG, "WebView is not allowed to keep the screen on")
        }

        originalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation()
        customViewCallback = callback
        customView = view

        //setRequestedOrientation(requestedOrientation)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR)
        val decorView = window.decorView as FrameLayout
        
        fullscreenContainerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscrren_video, null) as LinearLayout
        fullscreenContainerView?.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black))
        if (view is FrameLayout) {
            val child = view.focusedChild
            if (child is VideoView) {
                videoView = child
                child.setOnErrorListener(VideoCompletionListener())
                child.setOnCompletionListener(VideoCompletionListener())
            }
        } else if (view is VideoView) {
            videoView = view
            view.setOnErrorListener(VideoCompletionListener())
            view.setOnCompletionListener(VideoCompletionListener())
        }
        
        decorView.addView(fullscreenContainerView, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS)
        fullscreenContainerView?.addView(customView, 0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0).also { it.weight = 1f })
        fullscreenContainerView?.findViewById<AdView>(R.id.ad_view)?.let { AdsManager.get.initAdView(it) }
        decorView.requestLayout()
        setFullscreen(enabled = true, immersive = true)
        currentTab?.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)
    }
```

myxml code

layout_fullscreen_video.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    include layout="@layout/layout_ad_banner" 
</LinearLayout>
```

and This my layout_ad_banner

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
android:layout_width="match_parent"     
android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">   

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView         
android:id="@+id/ad_view"         
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
app:adSize="BANNER"         
app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />  
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not load Ad banner on landscape mode and make a [separate layout on landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations) without the Ad banner.

Comment: was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this? @DionAssydqi